# Submitting SSL HttpWebRequests with client certificates on Azure App Services

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to do a *very* simple HTTP/SSL request with a client certificate in an Azure Web App (App Service) with .NET. For context, it's to write logs to an Elasticsearch cluster.

Enabling tracing for `System.Net` and `System.Net.Sockets` shows that the request fails while attempting to load the private key for the client certificate - which was loaded *in memory*.

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [4064] SecureChannel#49205706 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
System.Net Information: 0 : [4064] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Error: 0 : [4064] AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0764] Socket#8628710::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [0764] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#53036123:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
System.Net Error: 0 : [0764] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#53036123::EndGetRequestStream - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Searching for `AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D` reveals that it's apparently to do with permissions in the certificate store - which I am **not** using.

My guess is that for some reason, `AcquireCredentialsHandle` tries to access a certificate store, which it fails to do because of the sandboxed environment of Azure Web Apps.

It definitely does not seem to be an IIS-specific issue, because again, it fails in a regular executable. The following code fails in a simple webjob.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IFHM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Path));

            var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://myapp.com");
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, errors) => true;
            req.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("client.pfx"));
            try
            {
                var resp = req.GetResponse();
                var respStr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(respStr);
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
                var errRespStr = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(errRespStr);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need to upload the .pfx file to the Azure WebApp and first make it accessible to your application code. You do this with the **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** app setting.

You could get the detail steps and demo code from [azure official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load#load-your-certificates)

Comment: Thank you. Apparently just setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` is enough to allow loading certificates from disk.

Comment: This was driving me INSANE!!!!! And to top it off, all that was needed was a silly config change in the portal. Sigh.

Comment: If you're loading certificates manually (via the file system or reading data from a database), you need to set `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` -- from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code).